# Using jQuery to turn an input button into a submit button is firing a submit event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm working on a Carousel Form and would like to multipurpose the control buttons when bounds are reached. The original state has the expected operations of Previous and Next. When the final view is reached by clicking the next button I am checking the current position of the viewport and using this bit of code to turn the button into a submit,

Here is the HTML that I am manipulating, it is simply an input button,

```
<input type="button" id="next" value="Next">
```

And the accompanying jQuery which is firing off from the EventHandler for the input.

```
if (trigger == "next") {
  console.log("Current: " + currentPosition);
  if (currentPosition > MIN_BOUND) {
    currentPosition -= FORM_WIDTH;
    if (currentPosition == MIN_BOUND) {
      $("#next").attr("type", "submit");
      $("#next").val("Submit");
    }
  }
}
```

This action is doing what I expected, but additionally it is also submitting the form, which is something I did not expect. I'm curious as to why this might be happening.

Edit: As an aside. Using a carousel as a form isn't something I've thought of doing, my supervisor suggested I develop this. My original intent was a long form or just using ajax calls to dynamically store information and swap content. Is a 'Carousel Form' even a good idea? I can't recall running into them myself. I do having everything pre-loaded as it feels very fast, and a progress bar helps from a UX standpoint as I know what is expected of me.

Comment: Add the HTML. Would be easy to understand your issue

Comment: I can say for sure that submission doesn't happen in this code snippet

Comment: These are the only two parts involved in this operation. The form itself has about '7 columns' which are clicked through and on the final click after checking the position the 'Next' button turns into a 'Submit' button. It seems like it is holding onto an Event behind the scenes and firing it off, causing the form to submit.

Comment: @ScotMatson - are you changing the button type during the click of the button? Where is the code that you showed located?

Comment: @Igor Yes, condition to modify the button is within the .click. I didn't expect that these would be tied together but that seems like it could make sense. I placed it there so it wouldn't be checking the condition constantly but I guess that won't be avoidable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the click finish before changing the button type:

```
if (currentPosition == MIN_BOUND) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#next").attr("type", "submit");
    $("#next").val("Submit");
  }, 10);
}
```

Comment: This works! Thanks @Igor. I've also posted an alternative solution that I concluded to at the same time you were submitting this. Both methods give the intended behavior.

I don't know if there is a right answer but credit definitely goes to you. Thanks for taking the time to help me think about this.

Answer (score 0):

Preventing the default behavior was all that was required. A simple solution but one that I did not think would work because I believed to would also prevent the default behavior of the submit button, but this was not the case.

```
    if (currentPosition == MIN_BOUND) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#next").attr("type", "submit");
      $("#next").val("Submit");
    }
```

Allowed me to prevent the default submission during the state transition but also retained the submit button functionality during the next click since the default behavior would only be prevented during the change.

I couldn't find a similar question to compare this sequence of events to, so hopefully this solution, as simple as it is, will benefit someone other than myself.